# How to unit test a handler which wraps an http call to an external service

Tags: unit-testing, go

i have a handler function which is called CreateObject. This function wraps at the same time a POST request to an external API which i dont control. If I want to unit test it, the problem I face is that I can't be posting new objects to the external service every time I run the test. So I would like to know if there is a way to mock this with Go or any workaround.

Many thanks.

**package main**

```
func main() {

router := mux.NewRouter()

router.HandleFunc("/groups", services.CreateObject).Methods("POST")
c := cors.New(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"},
    AllowedHeaders:   []string{"*"},
    ExposedHeaders:   []string{"*"},
})

handler := c.Handler(router)

http.ListenAndServe(":3000", handler)
```

**package objects**

```
  func CreateObject(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {



        var newobject Object
        _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&newobject )

        //Do things

        jsonStr, err := json.Marshal(newobject)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", ExternalURL+"/object", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))


        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        client := &http.Client{}
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)


        if resp.StatusCode < 200 || resp.StatusCode > 299 {
            w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            w.Write(body)

        } else {
            w.WriteHeader(201)
        }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options:

1) You can define an interface that has the exported method set of the http.Client.  You can then make a package-level variable of this type, which defaults to a *http.Client.  Instead of using a *http.Client in CreateObject, you'd use this variable.  Since it's an interface, you can mock out the client easily.  The interface would look like this:

```
type HTTPClient interface {
    Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
    Get(url string) (resp *http.Response, err error)
    Post(url string, contentType string, body io.Reader) (resp *http.Response, err error)
    PostForm(url string, data url.Values) (resp *http.Response, err error)
    Head(url string) (resp *http.Response, err error)
}
```

Since you only call Do(), however, your mock only needs to define an actual test implementation for Do.  We often use a function-field style for this:

```
type MockClient struct {
    DoFunc func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
    // other function fields, if you need them
}

func (m MockClient) Do(req *http.Request) (r *http.Response, err error) {
    if m.DoFunc != nil {
        r, err = m.DoFunc(req)
    }
    return
}

// Define the other 4 methods of the HTTPclient as trivial returns

var mockClient HTTPClient = MockClient{
    DoFunc: func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
        return nil, nil
    },
}

var mockClientFail HTTPClient = MockClient{
    DoFunc: func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed")
    },
}
```

2) Stand up your own HTTP mock server on a localhost port and, within your tests, change your ExternalURL variable to point to it instead.  This allows you to actually test the dialing (which makes it more of a functional test than a unit test), while still effectively "mocking" the external endpoint.

In either case, make sure you also write some regression tests to make sure the external endpoint still works as expected.

**Edit:** Per dm03514, Go already has an mock HTTP server built in: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/

Comment: i think go even has HTTP mock server builtin to help with this https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/

Comment: Edited to add, thanks for pointing that out.  I don't mock HTTP servers enough, I'm usually doing direct TCP sockets >.<